# Master detail Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a component which displays a list, that when I click on each item in the list, it should display some data. The data should come from a child component. 
The problem is that now when I click on each element, it will display the data for the whole list. What I try to achieve, is that only for the clicked link it will display the data.

Here's my code of the component's HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor = "let book of myBooks; let i = index" > // myBooks is array of books
       Book ID: {{book.id}} , Book name: {{book.name}}. 
      <a href="#" (click)="toggleBookDetails(i)">Book details</a> (click to expand): 
  <div>
      <display-details 
            [showDetails] ="showDetails" 
            [bookDetails]     ="myBooks"
            [bookId]          ="bookId">

      </display-details>

  </div>

 </li>
```

toggleBookDetails(i) is just a function to toggle the view

`<display-details>` is the component that displays the details for each clickable link

This is the  component:

```
export class BookDetailsComponent {

  constructor( ) { }

   @Input() bookDetails: bookDetails;
   @Input() bookId: string;
   @Input() showDetails: boolean;
 }
```

and this is the view:

```
<div *ngIf="showDetails">
        {{bookDetails[bookId].details.title}},  
        {{bookDetails[bookId].details.ISBN}}

</div>
```

What happens now that when I click on any link it will display the details for  the whole list. I want to display the details only for the specific link that clicked.

Thanks.

Comment: Showing `toggleBookDetails(i)` method will help

Comment: toggleBookDetails(index){
    this.showDetails = !this.showDetails;
    this.bookId = index;
  }

Comment: You need to turn `showDetails` into an array of length `i`. Then send in `showDetails[i]`. Currently you only have one `showDetails` so there is only one variable to keep track of _all_ the books. Hope this help give you an understanding of how to make a solution! :)

Comment: Thanks! work. Just a small question: I need to double click in the first time that I click the link - maybe it because the first value is either undefined or false? If yes, how can I push the first value of true to the array, so I'll not have to double click in the first time? Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have most of this done - just some minor changes:

1. Change the bookDetails to bind to book
2. Make visibility based on an array which is indexed by i
3. Send book.id, not the whole bookId
4. Optional use a button rather than  and bind to the same click handler

In your toggle, be sure to set showDetails[i]to true or false as appropriate.  Make sure you initialize it as an empty array when you declare it:  showDetails:boolean[]=[];

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor = "let book of myBooks; let i = index" > // myBooks is array of books
       Book ID: {{book.id}} , Book name: {{book.name}}. 
      <a href="#" (click)="toggleBookDetails(i)">Book details</a> (click to expand): 
  <div>
      <display-details 
            [showDetails] ="showDetails[i]" 
            [bookDetails]     ="book"
            [bookId]          ="book.id">

      </display-details>

  </div>

 </li>
```

Your Show Details would be:

```
    toggleBookDetails(i:number){
     if(this.showDetails[i]==false){
          this.showDetails[i]=true;
       }else{
          this.showDetails[i]=false;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! perfectly works. Just a small question: I need to double click in the first time that I click the link - maybe it because the first value is either undefined or false? If yes, how can I push the first value of true to the array, so I'll not have to double click in the first time? Thanks again

Comment: Did you remember to declare the array as an empty array in your declarations?  That should fix the problem.  Public Myarray:Boolean = []

Comment: Yes, I did it. And still I need to click twice at the first time

Comment: I was try to push true to the first element in the array but it gave me error - what's the proper way to push inside the class? I tried showDetails[0] = true, showDetails.push('true') and got error

Comment: It should work.  Instead of binding to [showDetails]=... use an ngIf statement like this:  <display-details *ngIf=showdetails[i]  [bookdetails]=book [bookId]=book.id> If not pls post all the code for this template

Comment: Ok, here's how I solved it: when I initialize the array, instead of empty array I do it like this: showDetails: boolean[] = [false, false, false]; , then I only need to click once.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help